# Change NSAttributedString html links color

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring, asyncdisplaykit

Trying to display a ASTextNode (same as UILabel from AsyncDisplayKit) to display an html text. I simply have to set the label's attributed text.

There is how i work my string :

Using this extension i transform the HTML text into a NSAttributedString :

```
extension String {
    var html2AttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
        guard let data = data(using: .utf8) else { return nil }
        do {
            return try NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return  nil
        }
    }
    var html2String: String {
        return html2AttributedString?.string ?? ""
    }
}
```

Then i set my label details :

```
 self.displayContent = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: content.html2AttributedString!)
 self.displayContent?.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont.fontMainFeedContentFont(), range: NSRange.init(location: 0, length: self.displayContent!.length))
```

So i have my label with my font and it's ok, problem is that i can't change the links colors of my label, it's a system blue that i do want.

Any idea how can i change the links' colors ?

Thanks.

Comment: By link color, do you mean underline color?

Comment: Nope, the text color is black, the links colors are blue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an answer for this in Swift 4.0

```
termsAndPolicyTextView.linkTextAttributes = [
    NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.red
]
```

Full code:
Note: I can't set multiple color in a single `textView`.

```
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: termsAndPolicyText)

attributedString.addAttribute(
    NSAttributedString.Key.link,
    value: "https://google.co.in",
    range: (termsAndPolicyText as NSString).range(of: "Terms or service")
)

attributedString.addAttribute(
    NSAttributedString.Key.link,
    value: "https://google.co.in", // Todo set our terms and policy link here
    range: (termsAndPolicyText as NSString).range(of: "Privacy & Legal Policy")
)

attributedString.addAttributes(
    [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.NMSTextColor(with: 0.6)],
    range: NSRange(location: 0, length: termsAndPolicyText.count)
)

termsAndPolicyTextView.linkTextAttributes = [
    NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.termstextViewTextColor()
]
termsAndPolicyTextView.attributedText = attributedString
termsAndPolicyTextView.textAlignment = .center
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok guys, i found an ugly way to do this.

After transforming the html text to an NSMutableAttributedString, i simply loop thought all attributes, when i see an "NSLink" attribute i simply add an attribute for the attribute's range :

```
self.myString!.enumerateAttributes(in: NSRange(0..<myString!.length), options: []) { (attributes, range, _) -> Void in
                for (attribute, object) in attributes {
                    if attribute == "NSLink" {
                        print("Attribute = \(attribute) -- \(object)")
                        self.myString?.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: StyleKit.color_blue_bright, range: range)
                        self.myString?.addAttribute(NSUnderlineColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.clear, range: range)
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The link color can be changed in the following way. The below example will demonstrate that:

```
let attributedText:NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "why?")
attributedText.addAttribute(NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName, value: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedText.length))
attributedText.addAttribute(NSUnderlineColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.black, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedText.length))
attributedText.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.black, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedText.length))
```

Also, you have to make the following changes to the `UITextView` that's displaying it.

```
textView.linkTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.black]
```

If you do not want to use `UITextView` to do this, you can simply use [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel). It has `linkAttributes` and `activeLinkAttributes` property which you can use to achieve the desired behaviour without using `UITextView`.

Please let me know if it works or not. Feel free to suggest edits to make this better :)

Comment: it's not a textview that i use, i can't it's in tableview, i do not want to calculate the height, i'll try thank u

Comment: NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName simply underline the link, i want to change the text color of the link.

Comment: I believe you already tried it using `attributedText.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.black, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedText.length))`. It didn't work for me. Only `UITextView` has `linkTextAttributes` property, and that is the only way which doesn't use coretext

Comment: You can use `UITextView` in a tableView and make it non-editable. Otherwise, one of the ways to do it would be using `TTTAttributedLabel`. https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel

Comment: No i need to achieve 60 fps scrolling... No UITextView and size calculation, so looks like not possible ... Thanks.

Comment: By size calculation, I believe you are thinking about resizing `UITextView` when user types something in it. There is no need for size calculation. You can simply use an `UITextView` like `UILabel` by making it non editable.

Comment: No it's on a table view, cell's size are dynamic, i never said user's interaction were enabled.

Comment: So, are you using `UITableviewAutomaticDimension` or calculating height for each cell?

Comment: No i'm using AsyncDisplayKit from Facebook. No size calculation, size calculation & UI rendering appears on the background. No need to handle this and that's why it is so fast.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the info :)

Comment: See my answer that i wrote, not the fatest solution but it works !

Answer (score -1):

Links color is default of attributed string. Can be specified by using css.

```
extension String {
    var html2AttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
        let html = """

<style type="text/css">
a, a:link, a:visited {
    color: inherit !important;
}
</style>
""" + self
        guard let data = html.data(using: .utf8) else { return nil }
        ...
```